# Kafka producer Interceptor

Tags: java, apache-kafka, interceptor

I am trying add a Interceptor to do validation for the messages published by the producer to Kafka topic. I need to do few validations in addition to Schema validation which is performed by Kafka topic. Steps I have followed are as follows.

1. I have written a Java class extending ProducerInterceptor Interface.
2. Compiled the class and created a jar file which is placed in a folder included in the classpath.
3. Added `interceptors.classes = classname` to producer.properties inside Kafka installation.

But when I publish message to the topic the custom interceptor class which I have written is not invoked. (I am not getting any errors also. Messages are published to topic perfectly.)

I haver referred https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-42%3A+Add+Producer+and+Consumer+Interceptors

Answer (score 1):

This question is pretty old, so I assume you found a solution in the meantime. However, just in case it helps someone else, I found that my `ProducerInterceptor` class, which dispatches messages to different topics based on the contents of the message, was not invoked unless my stream already had a specified output.

My first attempt looked something like this because I thought I didn't need to specify an output topic. This does NOT work:

```
val builder: KStreamBuilder = new KStreamBuilder
val input = builder.stream("input-topic")

val stream: KafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(builder, streamsConfigWithProducerInterceptor)
stream.start()
```

But this does:

```
val builder: KStreamBuilder = new KStreamBuilder
val input = builder.stream("input-topic").through("dummy-output-topic")

val stream: KafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(builder, streamsConfigWithProducerInterceptor)
stream.start()
```

It's worth noting that nothing gets published to that `dummy-output-topic` in the second example, and that using `to` instead of `through` also appears to work the same way.

In my case, I was invoking `map` to change the records before using the interceptor to dispatch them to different topics, so my code actually looks more like this:

```
val builder: KStreamBuilder = new KStreamBuilder
val input = builder.stream("input-topic")
    .map(new CustomKeyValueMapper)
    .through("dummy-output-topic")

val stream: KafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(builder, streamsConfigWithProducerInterceptor)
stream.start()
```

I hope those examples help anyone working with `ProducerInterceptor`s who made the same mistake I did.